# High CPU AAS on SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm seeing high CPU AAS on a query that is executed a lot, way over my max vCPU:

[image]

Here is the full SQL:

```
SELECT 
    "api_relations".* 
FROM 
    "api_relations" 
WHERE 
    "api_relations"."source_id" = $1 
    AND "api_relations"."destination_entity_id" = $2 
    AND "api_relations"."company_id" = $3 
    AND "api_relations"."source_entity_id" = $4 
    AND "api_relations"."destination_app_id" = $5 
    AND "api_relations"."source_app_id" = $6 
LIMIT ?
```

This query tries to find a record in a 3 million records table, and is executed by multiple processes at the same time, but not trying to find the same record.

I also already have an index on the columns on the where section.

Is this a case of just changing my instance type to have more vCPU to fix it, or can I improve this by changing something?

The funny thing is, it was fine a week ago and nothing major was changed, only more records were added to the table.

EXPLAIN Result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=553) (actual time=0.034..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4 read=1
  I/O Timings: read=0.005
  ->  Index Scan using index_api_relation_list on api_relations  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=553) (actual time=0.032..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((company_id = 171) AND (source_entity_id = 11) AND (destination_entity_id = 11) AND (source_app_id = 1) AND (destination_app_id = 3))
        Filter: ((source_id)::text = '70041486'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=4 read=1
        I/O Timings: read=0.005
Planning Time: 0.254 ms
Execution Time: 0.065 ms
```

Comment: Either your index is no good, or the condition is not selective enough. Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it can't be that statement, since that executes in under 1 millisecond. Perhaps you can use `pg_stat_statements` to find out your problem query.